# PyRestTest: Print out passed test cases as well

Tags: pyresttest

I'm using PyRestTest on linux to test some REST APIs. On the terminal, I only see test cases that failed. How can I get resttest.py to print out the passes test cases as well? I tried looking at the src for resttest.py, but couldn't find a switch. The command line args for resttest.py also do not have a switch to print out the passed test cases. The --verbose option only seems to print out cURL output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the command line, set the --log argument to 'info.'

Incidentally, I am the author of PyRestTest.

Answer (score 1):

the code that reads the response code is in run_test of resttest.py. I just modified that location to printout the success message

Comment: The passing tests can already be listed if the log level is set to info or lower: https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest/blob/master/pyresttest/resttest.py#L678